# Hyper-parameter tuning using pure ranger package in R

Tags: r, model, random-forest, hyperparameters

Love the speed of the ranger package for random forest model creation, but can't see how to tune mtry or number of trees. I realize I can do this via caret's train() syntax, but I prefer the speed increase that comes from using pure ranger.

Here's my example of basic model creation using ranger (which works great):

```
library(ranger)
data(iris)

fit.rf = ranger(
  Species ~ .,
  training_data = iris,
  num.trees = 200
)

print(fit.rf)
```

Looking at the official documentation for tuning options, it seems like the csrf() function may provide the ability to tune hyper-parameters, but I can't get the syntax right:

```
library(ranger)
data(iris)

fit.rf.tune = csrf(
  Species ~ .,
  training_data = iris,
  params1 = list(num.trees = 25, mtry=4),
  params2 = list(num.trees = 50, mtry=4)
)

print(fit.rf.tune)
```

Results in:

```
Error in ranger(Species ~ ., training_data = iris, num.trees = 200) : 
  unused argument (training_data = iris)
```

And I'd prefer to tune with the regular (read: non-csrf) rf algorithm ranger provides. Any idea as to a hyper-parameter tuning solution for either path in ranger? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are at least two errors:

First, the function `ranger` does not have a parameter called `training_data`. Your error message `Error in ranger(Species ~ ., training_data = iris, num.trees = 200) : unused argument (training_data = iris)` refers to that. You can see that when you look at `?ranger` or `args(ranger)`.

Second, the function `csrf`, on the other hand, has `training_data` as input, but also requires `test_data`. Most importantly, these two arguments do not have any defaults, implying that you must provide them. The following works without problems:

```
fit.rf = ranger(
  Species ~ ., data = iris,
  num.trees = 200
)

fit.rf.tune = csrf(
Species ~ .,
training_data = iris,
test_data = iris,
params1 = list(num.trees = 25, mtry=4),
params2 = list(num.trees = 50, mtry=4)
)
```

Here, I have just provided `iris` as both training and test dataset. You would obviously not want to do that in your real application. Moreover, note that `ranger` also take `num.trees` and `mtry` as input, so you could try tuning it there.

Comment: Fantastic info, thanks! To your knowledge, there's no non-csrf route to hyper-parameter tuning in ranger? Also, Zheyuan, I did originally ask if a non-csrf option was available (and not just for a fix for the documented csrf implementation).

Comment: Very generous, guys, thanks. Just a note, coffeinjunky--even though the error message I posted said I had used the ranger function, I had actually used the csrf function (not sure if you want to edit your response). I'll email Marvin Wright (the maintainer) an FYI about this. Thanks, again!

Comment: Also, coffeinjunky, if you're editing, would you mind adding an example of param1, param2 syntax for tuning with ranger function? Thanks!

Comment: Just add `num.trees=5` or any other number, or `mtry=5` or any other number, to your call. As in `ranger(Species ~ ., data = iris, num.trees = 200, mtry=5)`

Answer (score 18):

To answer my (unclear) question, apparently ranger has no built-in CV/GridSearch functionality. However, here's how you do hyper-parameter tuning with ranger (via a grid search) outside of caret. Thanks goes to Marvin Wright (the maintainer of ranger) for the code. Turns out caret CV with ranger was slow for me because I was using the formula interface (which should be avoided).

```
ptm <- proc.time()
library(ranger)
library(mlr)

# Define task and learner
task <- makeClassifTask(id = "iris",
                        data = iris,
                        target = "Species")

learner <- makeLearner("classif.ranger")

# Choose resampling strategy and define grid
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 5)
ps <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("mtry", 3, 4),
                   makeDiscreteParam("num.trees", 200))

# Tune
res = tuneParams(learner, task, rdesc, par.set = ps,
           control = makeTuneControlGrid())

# Train on entire dataset (using best hyperparameters)
lrn = setHyperPars(makeLearner("classif.ranger"), par.vals = res$x)
m = train(lrn, iris.task)

print(m)
print(proc.time() - ptm) # ~6 seconds
```

For the curious, the caret equivalent is

```
ptm <- proc.time()
library(caret)
data(iris)

grid <-  expand.grid(mtry = c(3,4))

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "CV",
                           number = 5,
                           verboseIter = TRUE)

fit = train(
  x = iris[ , names(iris) != 'Species'],
  y = iris[ , names(iris) == 'Species'],
  method = 'ranger',
  num.trees = 200,
  tuneGrid = grid,
  trControl = fitControl
)
print(fit)
print(proc.time() - ptm) # ~2.4 seconds
```

Overall, caret is the fastest way to do a grid search with ranger if one uses the non-formula interface.

Comment: Thanks for providing these solutions. Quick question, is it possible to include a list of num.tree hyperparameters within the search grid?

Answer (score 5):

Another way to tune the model is to create a manual grid, maybe there are better ways to train the model but this may be a different option.

```
hyper_grid <- expand.grid(
  mtry       = 1:4,
  node_size  = 1:3,
  num.trees = seq(50,500,50),
  OOB_RMSE   = 0
)

system.time(
  for(i in 1:nrow(hyper_grid)) {
    # train model
    rf <- ranger(
      formula        = Species ~ .,
      data           = iris,
      num.trees      = hyper_grid$num.trees[i],
      mtry           = hyper_grid$mtry[i],
      min.node.size  = hyper_grid$node_size[i],
      importance = 'impurity')
    # add OOB error to grid
    hyper_grid$OOB_RMSE[i] <- sqrt(rf$prediction.error)
  })
user  system elapsed 
3.17    0.19    1.36

nrow(hyper_grid) # 120 models
position = which.min(hyper_grid$OOB_RMSE)
head(hyper_grid[order(hyper_grid$OOB_RMSE),],5)
     mtry node_size num.trees     OOB_RMSE
6     2         2        50 0.1825741858
23    3         3       100 0.1825741858
3     3         1        50 0.2000000000
11    3         3        50 0.2000000000
14    2         1       100 0.2000000000

# fit best model
rf.model <- ranger(Species ~ .,data = iris, num.trees = hyper_grid$num.trees[position], importance = 'impurity', probability = FALSE, min.node.size = hyper_grid$node_size[position], mtry = hyper_grid$mtry[position])
rf.model
Ranger result

Call:
 ranger(Species ~ ., data = iris, num.trees = hyper_grid$num.trees[position], importance = "impurity", probability = FALSE, min.node.size = hyper_grid$node_size[position], mtry = hyper_grid$mtry[position]) 

    Type:                             Classification 
Number of trees:                  50 
Sample size:                      150 
Number of independent variables:  4 
Mtry:                             2 
Target node size:                 2 
Variable importance mode:         impurity 
Splitrule:                        gini 
OOB prediction error:             5.33 %
```

I hope it serves you.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `mlr` per default disables the internal parallelization of ranger. Set hyperparameter `num.threads` to the number of cores available to speed `mlr` up:

```
learner <- makeLearner("classif.ranger", num.threads = 4)
```

Alternatively, start a parallel backend via

```
parallelStartMulticore(4) # linux/osx
parallelStartSocket(4)    # windows
```

before calling `tuneParams` to parallelize the tuning.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [tuneRanger](https://github.com/PhilippPro/tuneRanger) R package, which is specifically designed for tuning ranger and uses predefined tuning parameters, hyperparameter spaces and intelligent tuning by using the out-of-bag observations.

Note, that random forest is not an algorithm were tuning makes a big difference, usually. But it can usually improve the performance a bit.